# How to decompose $\max(0, M-x) = f_1(x) - f_2(x)$ such that $\Vert f_1(x) + f_2(x)\Vert ^2$ is differentiable

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, differential-geometry

Let $f(x) = \max(0, M-x), x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $M$ is a constant.

How to decompose $f(x) = f_1(x) - f_2(x)$ such that $\Vert f_1(x) + f_2(x)\Vert^2$ is differentiable.